# Unit testing css with angular

Tags: html, css, angular, testing

Is there any way in which I could test say the `height` css property of an element?

I have a function that changes the height of a `div` and it would be nice to check in the tests that the function operates correctly...

**ie:**

```
<div #myDiv>Hello world</div>
```

---

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

myFunct() {
  this.myDiv.nativeElement.style.height = 500;
}
```

---

```
it('should increase div size', () => {
  // Here is where I get stuck...
});
```

### Update

Implementing a test such as:

```
it('should return correct height of dropdown when initialised', () => {
    component.myFunct();

    expect(component.dropdown.nativeElement.style.height).toBe(34);
  });
```

results in a test failure with message:

> Expected '' to be 500.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this...

1. Exposed the myDiv publicly
2. Setup the testbed for the component (usually added by default)
3. Add

> ```
> component.myFunct();
>
> expect(component.myDiv.nativeElement.style.height).toBe(500);
> ```

Comment: I had done something similar to this prior to posting the question. The problem I have when doing this, is that I get a failure and returned, `Expected '' to be 34.`...

Comment: Ah I understand what is going on now. I was mixing myself up between `nativeElement > style > height` and `nativeElement > clientHeight`